# Profiling a classic ASP application using AQTime

Tags: iis, asp-classic, profiling, jscript, aqtime

We have developed a large number of websites using ASP (jscript flavour), talking to the underlying intelligence layer (written in Delphi) through COM. These websites are running on IIS (5 and 6).

Over the years this ASP layer has grown into something quite heavy (no business logic, but lots of controller/scenario/view/ajax/etc handling), and we'd like to do a bit of performance tuning on it. According to the creator, AQTime (we have the latest version) can be used for this purpose (profiling both the serverside script and the underlying com objects in one go), but I simply can't figure out how to get it to work.

The help files explain how to profile COM dll's, ISAPI dll's and even client-side scripting, but not a word on how to profile the server-side script running on the ASP pages. Can't select .asp files as a "profiling module". Google is not helpful either.

Any word of advice on how to accomplish this? Alternative suggestions for profiling classic asp pages is welcome, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, **this isn't possible** (according to Official Support). Of the tree layers in our application,

1. Delphi code running on the server
2. ASP code (jscript) running on the server
3. Client-side jscript running on the client (ajax, etc)

AQTime can only profile (1) and (3). Although it can perfectly well profile windows scripting host .js files on the server, it will not profile .asp code. Which I was really hoping it would, seeing how both are executed through the same jscript.dll.